# ASP.NET, The status code returned from the server was: 500

Tags: c#, asp.net

A customer using a ASP.NET program I have just sent them is experiencing the error below, I had personally tested the program on 4 web server IIS6, 7, and 7.5, on 4 different networks and I never got this, the customer is using IIS6 with .Net 2.0 (as required). The program uses Windows authentication which may or may not be part of the problem. I'm stuck I don't know where to start with this. Any help is very much appreciated.

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   An unknown error occurred while
>   processing the request on the server.
>   The status code returned from the
>   server was: 500

Comment: IMHO you should try to gather a little more information. Application logs, server event logs for example.

Comment: Are you logging the exceptions with the stack trace? You will need to know where to look before trying to fix the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTTP error code 500 simply means "something bad happened on the server, but we're not going to tell you what that was".

You have to "ask" the server machine what went wrong. Look into the Windows event logs, the IIS logs, or your application's own logs to find out what the "something" is.

Comment: Windows event viewer is a good tip. Why do I always forget to check there!

Answer (score 2):

This error often means that there is some exception thrown inside your code, e.g. because a reference is null or something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `< > /` characters in your web form you will get this error.
Try placing `ValidateRequest="false"` in the page directive of your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have < > / characters in your web form you will get this error.
You must insert space or single quotation mark, right and left 
for example :

```
false: 1<TR<5
True:1< TR <5    or  1<'TR'<5
```